# XMLHttpRequest Error Checking- Better way to write this?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, try-catch

I wrote a webpage that runs from the desktop to grab information off of a public website. I am trying to make it to where 1) if there is no internet connection there is a alert 2) if there is a an internet connection but somehow the info was not retrieved correctly, the user would be alerted.

The try and catch works for the test if there is no internet connection.

I am using the xml.status codes for the second test...if the website is active but the info that is pulled is messed up....that test condition isn't working the way I wanted it. I tried giving the xml.open a bogus website and was expecting a non 200-300 status code. But it did not work...instead the catch statement was activated. Why is this? And is there a better way to write this?

Also, on a side note I had return ""; because I the calling variables that use this could not be have null or undefined: variable = getInfo(); n.setAttribute("placeholder", variable);

```
function getInfo() {
        var xml = null;
        xml = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
        try {
            xml.open("get", "http://example.asp", false);
            xml.send(null);
            if ((xml.status >= 200 && xml.status <= 300) || xml.status == 304) {
                var hi = xml.responseText;
                hi = hi.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "");
                var what1 = /winning_number_sm.*?ul/
                    var what2 = /\d+/g

                    hi = what1.exec(hi);
                var temp;
                for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
                    if (null !== (temp = what2.exec(hi))) {
                        numbers[i] = temp;
                    }
                }
                return numbers;
            } else {
                alert("Error Connecting to Website! You will have to eneter informatin by hand");
                return "";
            }
        } catch (e) {
            alert("No Internet Connection! You will have to enter information by hand");
            return "";
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can use jQuery framework but to get error from an ajax connection (test if a website is up) you can do easely that :

```
//your ajax object
var request = $.ajax({
  url: "http://www.exemple.com/script.php",
  type: "POST",
  data: {/*your datas*/},
  dataType: "html"
});

request.done(function(msg) {
  //make your stuff automatically
});

request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
  alert( "Error Connecting to Website! You will have to enter informatin by hand");
});
```

Comment: no, this is strictly for javascript and no jquery. thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

An other approch can be to call a local php script whose test distant url with curl function (ex : http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php)